# How should I add socket.io to a Next.js application?

Tags: next.js, socket.io, next.js13

I have a Next.js project.
I would like to implement socket.io or something similar.
Should I use a custom Next.js Express Adapter thing, or make an extra service that is just express+socket.io?

The server receives POST requests from another server/service, and with each POST I would like to push some parsed data live out to all the clients.

So I did make this with Express+React already, but as the react documentation states that you should no longer use create-react-app, but rather use next.js / remix, I went with Next.js.

The examples I found online doesn't really make sense since I want to emit the data from the server, not between two clients. Most of those examples use /api/socket for the clients to connect.